# Grouping / adding similar objects

Tags: powershell, sum, grouping

I am querying SCCM database to check the history of users who logged into a computer.

What I have so far works fine however there is a lot of data and I would like to group them all together. For example here is the output for one computer:

[image]

These are all logons of the same user (let's say JohnDoe123).
What I want is, instead of having like 30 entries for John, 20 entries for Jane, etc. I want a total of each user. For example:

```
Computer1 - JohnDoe123 - FullName - Latest time for LastConsoleUse - 500 (total number of console logons) - Latest TimeStamp - 50 000 (total minutes)
```

You see what I mean?

Obviously I can't sum up the LastConsoleUse and TimeStamp values, so ideally I would like to have just the latest value.

I'm trying `... | Group-Object -property SystemConsoleUser` but it's returning an hashtable which isn't the format I'm after:

[image]

I'm pretty confused when it comes to manipulating objects within an object like this, so thanks for your help!

```
#Hist Users SCCM
$ConnexionsUsagers  = $null

$poste = "X"

$SiteCode = "X"
$SiteServer = "X"

$ResourceID_Name = (Get-WmiObject -namespace root\sms\site_$SiteCode -computer $SiteServer -query "select ResourceId,Name from SMS_R_SYSTEM where SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name LIKE '%$poste%'")

$ConnexionsUsagers += foreach ($item in $ResourceID_Name) {
    $query = @"
SELECT *
FROM SMS_GH_System_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USER
WHERE SMS_GH_System_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USER.ResourceID
LIKE '%$($item.ResourceId)%'
"@

    Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\sms\site_$SiteCode -Computer $SiteServer -Query $query |
        Where-Object {$_.SystemConsoleUser -ne $null} |
        Select-Object @{name='Poste';expression={$item.Name}}, SystemConsoleUser,
            @{name='Nom complet';expression={Get-ADUser -Properties userprincipalname ($_.SystemConsoleUser -replace "X\\") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty userPrincipalName}},
            @{name='LastConsoleUse';expression={[DateTime]::ParseExact(($_.LastConsoleUse).Split('.')[0], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)}},
            NumberofConsoleLogons,
            @{name='TimeStamp';expression={[DateTime]::ParseExact(($_.TimeStamp).Split('.')[0], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)}},
            TotalUserConsoleMinutes
}

$ConnexionsUsagers |
    Sort-Object @{expression="Poste"; Ascending=$true}, @{expression="TimeStamp"; Descending=$true} |
    Out-GridView
```

Comment: I commend to your attention the [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result using `Group-Object` and `Measure-Object`.

```
$ConnexionsUsagers | Group-Object -Property SystemConsoleUser |
   Select-Object @{n='SystemConsoleUser';e={$_.Name}},
   @{n='Poste';e={($_.group | Group-Object -Property Poste -NoElement).Name -join ';'}},
   @{n='Nom Complet';e={($_.group | Group-Object -Property "Nom Complet" -NoElement).Name}},
   @{n='NumberOfConsoleLogons';e={($_.group.NumberOfConsoleLogons | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum}},
   @{n='TotalUserConsoleMinutes';e={($_.group.TotalUserConsoleMinutes | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum}},
   @{n='LastConsoleUse';e={$_.group.LastConsoleUse | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1}}
```

`Group-Object -Property PropertyName` groups the array of objects by `PropertyName`. Every unique value of PropertyName will be grouped into a single line or item in the resulting collection. PropertyName values will now be listed under the Name property with all other properties and their values being listed as an array of objects under the Group property. You can then access the Group property to access the remaining ungrouped properties and values. The `-NoElement` switch leaves off the Group property. It is simply a way to minimize the returned data when it is not needed.

`-join` operator is used just in case there are multiple computers used by the user. `-join ';'` joins an array of values into a single string delimited by the semi-colon.

Comment: This is really interesting and works perfecly. I just added an extra sort at the end and it's perfection. If you don't mind, could you please explain a bit what is happening? I understand you get access to the group, then pipe that into another group-object? What is happening with -noelement and -join? Much appreciated, that was extremely educating.

Comment: @Rakha, I added some explanation. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Perfection my friend! Just leveled up my understanding of objects right here. Can't upvote enough.